# Proof a Natural (n) is Zero

Tags: proof, idris

I am trying to learn the idris paradigm and still struggling.  Here i have a function isZero that takes some natural Nat and returns True or False.

My issue is with the non-relexive case.

```
namespace Numbers

  data Nat : Type where
    Zero : Numbers.Nat
    Successor : Numbers.Nat -> Numbers.Nat

  isZero: Numbers.Nat -> Prelude.Bool.Bool
  isZero Zero = True
  isZero _ = False

  isNotZero: Numbers.Nat -> Prelude.Bool.Bool
  isNotZero Zero = False
  isNotZero _ = True

  proofNIsZero : (n : Numbers.Nat) -> isZero n = Bool.True
  proofNIsZero Zero = Refl
  proofNIsZero (Successor _) = ?rhs
```

It seems obvious to reason that some Successor to any Nat cannot be Zero.  But my struggle is in the proof.  The Type of the ?rhs hole is

```
--------------------------------------
rhs : False = True
```

Trying to navigate what I think should be (and will one day be) simple has led to `uninhabited`, `Void`, `absurd` and `impossible`.  None of which I can disambiguate.

Perhaps those are the keys - but I cannot decipher!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering as I think I relaized that perphaps the proof above wasn't stated correctly.  I added the statement that asserted `n = Zero`, which allow for the `isZero n = Bool.True` to have meaning.  the `n = Zero` carries forward as `prf` and allows me to declare `absurd prf` as `isZero n = Bool.True` cannot hold true if `n` is `Successor` to some `Nat`.

```
  Uninhabited (Successor _ = Zero) where
    uninhabited Refl impossible

  proofNIsZero : (n : Numbers.Nat) -> n = Zero -> isZero n = Bool.True
  proofNIsZero Zero prf = Refl
  proofNIsZero (Successor _) prf = absurd prf
```

Is there another approach or way to think of defining these as to not get caught in a pitfall?